Scary movie about spiders
I saw a scary movie about spiders about 10 years ago, and I came across this image which I am sure is from the movie. Can anyone identify the movie?


Any additional information that could help with identification? Or did you just pick some random picture from the web?

Reminds me of The Thing (1982), but it isn't it.

@ChristianRau There was an article about spiders  and this was one of the pictures used but it didn't name the movie directly. no, it wasn't random. They also used images from Arachnophobia which I have seen many times.

http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/916/should-we-allow-id-questions-that-boil-down-to-jsut-an-image

Well, now I know what my nightmares will be about tonight.

It is Spiders (2000). See here on IMDB.
The trailer even shows a character in a suit like within the picture above, in agony. It gives the impression that the spiders breed and use the humans as hosts.Stars include Lana Parrilla, currently the Mayor/Evil Queen on Once Upon a Time.Here's the IMDB plot summary:
A DNA experiment on a rare breed of spider is taking place on a NASA space shuttle, when a freak meteor shower engulfs the shuttle, causing everything to go horribly wrong. One survivor is found on the ship and watched over in a secret location deep in the California desert. The problem continues, as the survivor isn't alone, as another deadly spiders climbs out of him and goes on a rampage around the ship. Curious reporter Marci Eyre must now survive, escape and warn everyone before the spider reaches outside the desert.Here's the youtube link of the trailer in French

hehe! So cheesy! I believe you're correct and this is in fact the one I'm looking for.
